# java - RegEx replace all but

Tags: java, regex

I've come across a problem with using Regular Expressions in Java. I'm trying to replace everything in a string that doesn't match my expression.
Example:

```
String string = "This is test string (1) of 10";
```

Basically, I need to remove all the characters in the string to get the value inside the brackets to change it later on. I though that the following would work:

```
string.replaceAll("^[\\([0-9]\\)]", "(" + nextNumber  +")" );
```

However, it doesn't. I have also tried:

```
string.replaceAll("(?!\\([0-9]\\)])", "(" + nextNumber  +")" );
```

Does anyone know of a better way of getting the value inside the brackets, or could you tell me how I can replace all the characters in the string except the value inside the brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
string.replaceAll("\\([0-9]\\)", "(" + nextNumber  +")" );
```

There is no need of `^` that represents start of the line.

If the number is more than one digit then try `\\([0-9]+\\)` and you can use `\\d` instead of `[0-9]`

For more info have a look at [Java Regex Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)